# Python save Excel .xlsx to CSV/XML and also save styling Information for conversion back into .xsls

Tags: python, excel, xml, csv, openpyxl

My Python program converts Excel files (.xlsx) into a CSV file using Panda's read_excel and to_csv function, and at some point in the future, the CSV is converted back into an Excel file. Maintaining the data is fine, but of course all of the formatting and styling is gone. So I could use some help in being able to capture the that information to use when after converting the CSV back into an Excel file.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

EXCEL_PATH_FROM = r'C:\absolute\path\to\excel.xlsx'
EXCEL_PATH_TO = r'C:\absolute\path\to\other\excel.xlsx'
CSV_PATH = r'C:\absolute\path\to\csv.csv'

# read excel and convert to csv
def saveData():
    read_excel = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_PATH_FROM)
    print("writing csv...")
    read_excel.to_csv(CSV_PATH, index=None, header=True)

# get csv data and import that data into an excel file
def createFromData():
   csv = pd.read_csv(CSV_PATH)
   excel = pd.ExcelWriter(EXCEL_PATH_TO, engine='xlsxwriter')
   csv.to_excel(excel, index=None)
   excel.save()
```

Some ideas I had were to save the Excel as a XML and insert format and style information as attributes or something, or to create both a CSV and XML from the Excel (one for data and one for styling). One problem I have is figuring out how to access that information.

Are there currently any packages that support Python 3 (currently using 3.8) that could help simplify this process? I dug through openpyxl's documentation and they have some stylesheet classes that aren't meant to be used directly I don't think and I couldn't figure out how to use them directly.

Comment: If you want to preserve style information you will need to work with openpyxl directly.

Comment: @CharlieClark would you happen to know of any way of going about that? I am having trouble finding other questions that are about this

Comment: Is preserving the existing formatting essential, an alternative would be to add your own formatting.

Comment: @MartinEvans That is what I am actually trying to go for. Store the actual excel data into a CSV, and store the formatting in another file. When it is time to recreate the excel, fill the data back in using the CSV and use the information from the formatting file to format it. So the main problem is finding a way to capture the formatting and put it into another file. If that is solved, using the formatting information file to format a new excel shouldn't be an issue since I would expect it to be the reverse/opposite of what was done to extract it (I could be wrong on that however)